# How to prevent Mac from changing the order of Desktops/Spaces

Tags: macos, mac, spaces, mission-control

You may have encountered a situation in which Mac changes the order of desktops based on some events like alerts on a program or a web page in browser.

How could I disable this logical change?

Note: I'm using El Capitan, but I had this problem since Mavericks.

Answer (score 810, accepted):

### General Solution

> System Settings/Preferences > Search for "Spaces" > Uncheck Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use

### Newer MacOS Ventura (v13)

> System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Scroll down to Mission Control section > Uncheck Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use

[image]

---

#### Older macOS (v12 and older)

System Preferences > Mission Control
Uncheck Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use.

[image]

This will fix the order of all your regular Spaces - but not Fullscreen spaces, which always go to the right of existing numbered Spaces.

---

From comments: Note this cannot fix the Mac confusing which external screen is which. That's not user-controlled at all, & seems to occur mainly [though not always] when the external screens are identical.

*Late note:*
This echoes the behaviour of Cmd/Tab or equivalent in most operating systems, so could be considered a 'sensible' default.
 <sub>just to save this attracting *even more* comments on why it was a good/bad choice of default.</sub>

Comment: Seems I've never looked for it precisely. It's the first options in the list. thank you.

Comment: I cannot imagine why anyone would want that to be the default.  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have two extra monitors, and about 25% of the time after waking the Mac up from sleep, they flip Spaces. Super annoying. This has been a problem from Mavericks to now (MacOS).

Comment: @NathanBeach it helps users that don't understand spaces, so it helps users who *need* it to be the default setting. :)

Comment: It does it even if I turn off 'Displays have separate Spaces'

Comment: Wow.  I had thought my computer was glitching for about a year now.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you thank you. 5 years with mac and I never thought about finding a solution for this crap.

Comment: The MOST BUGGIEST feature I've ever seen.

Comment: This auto-rearranging has been happening for me recently (macOS 10.15), even with this unchecked. Anyone else having this problem and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. No-one will ever see it down here other than the poster of the answer. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: All this lost years!!

Comment: Apple "helping" you

Comment: @ahnbizcad - by making it echo the behaviour of [modifier]/Tab in almost all operating systems...

Comment: You'r a genius. Sometimes is really hate apple for stuff like this.

Comment: Just one word. THANKS. This behaviour was bothering me for a couple of months now. Did not know this existed

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice; I find this answer every time I have to set up a new Mac.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the terminal to change the setting.

To disable rearrangement:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock "mru-spaces" -bool "false" && killall Dock
```

To enable rearrangement:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock "mru-spaces" -bool "true" && killall Dock
```