# Switch between last accessed mission control workspace with key

Tags: keyboard, macos, desktop, mission-control

Back when I used Linux I had a window manager similar to the macOS window manager, which had the same concept of different workspaces/desktops. It had a very useful additional feature, that you could map a keyboard key to let you switch between your current and previous desktop (instead of specifying the number). For example if I was on desktop #6 and switched to desktop #4, I could press i.e. `alt+tab` to immediately switch back to #6, and press again to switch back to #4 etc.

I've already enabled the `^n` Mission Control keyboard shortcuts. But I was hoping there'd be a way to switch between the current/last accessed desktop quicker, without remembering what desktop I was last on and keeping my hands in an awkward position.

I would be OK using an external program or shell script.

Comment: You actually just need the opposite of this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214348/how-to-prevent-mac-from-changing-the-order-of-desktops-spaces - check the box instead of unchecking, then the last screen will always be 'next'.