# How can I go to the previous desktop in Mission Control using a hot key?

Tags: keyboard, desktop, mission-control, keybindings

Say, I have 10 desktops. I'm on the desktop 2. I switch to the deskotp 7 using the F3 key and touchpad. Is there a standard hot key for switching back to the deskotp 2? And then back to the deskotp 7.

Similar to Alt+Tab, but for the desktops.

Comment: Do the opposite of this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/214348/85275 then ctrl/left or right will toggle between the last two - though you will lose your numbering. Alternatively, use ctrl/number to access directly.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's already done

Comment: Then go back to that answer & use direct numbers instead. There's no command for 'last used space', though Cmd/Tab would do the equivalent if you have your Spaces set correctly.

Comment: If you know which desktops you want to switch to just use they numbers i.e ctrl 2, ctrl 7, ctrl 2 ...

Comment: One thing to note is that if you have an extended keyboard with a 10-key, even though they look the same in prefs, those keys are actually different from the ones above qwerty. The default key commands use the qwerty keys.

Comment: @Buscar웃 doesn't work

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't ask about the direct numbers

Comment: What do you mean it does not work ? did you enable it in the system preferences > Keyboard shortcuts > Mission Control ? does it show all your desktops there with numbers associated ?

Comment: I know you didn't ask about the direct numbers.... but what you want cannot be done directly by key command... so we're trying to figure out an alternative for you

Comment: @Buscar웃 & nylypej - the key commands are not enabled by default. You need to specifically switch on each one in system prefs>keyboard>shortcuts>mission control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using keyboard shortcuts to switch Desktops.

Open System preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Click on the Mission control.

Desktops will show there with number associated to it.

Check all you want to switch.

Use "ctrl" and press number to switch.

[image]

Comment: how do i switch back and forth?

Comment: same, just hold `ctrl` and press the number you whish